# Why doesn't `\\` make a newline in TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf

This code

```
\tikz \graph [layered layout] {
"I want newline after comma:" -> "Hello,\\ World.";
};
```

just gets rid of the whitespace between the "," and the "W" of "World" below:

[image]

Why doesn't it make a newline?

Comment: this would be consistent with `\mbox{hello\\world}` which similarly does not break, you need a fixed width mode in tikz (which makes a parbox)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: How do I do that? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
\tikz [text centered] \graph [layered layout, nodes = {align=center}] {
"I want newline after comma:" -> "Hello,\\World.";
};
```

[image]

Comment: I don't want all the text's widths restricted, though.